# Ignore 'could not resolve ...' errors React Native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, babeljs, umd

I am using [this library](https://github.com/ulid/javascript) in my React Native app, but I am having a problem as it tries to `require` crypto. In a node environment, `require`-ing an unavailable module would throw an Error, which could then be caught and handled. However, the packager will not package the app as it couldn't resolve the module. Is there any way to ignore these errors and just have an error thrown on runtime?

Comment: Did you notice the build of that package is failing!

Comment: @RaajNadar I checked the build log, and it seems like it failed just because the connection to github timed out. I am able to use the library just fine in node.

Comment: Stop and start the packager again..

Comment: @RaajNadar how would that help? The module will still try to require a package that isn't installed... I have restarted it several times with no results by the way.

Comment: Maybe you are missing any dependencies?

Comment: @RaajNadar maybe my question isn't clear enough. I know that I am missing the module that I am trying to require, and I won't be able to easily change that. However, the module encloses the `require` call in a try block, so it is normally able to detect when the require fails and can then use a fallback. However, the RN packager will not package the app at all, meaning that the fallback can not be used.

Comment: Why don't you edit the file inside node_modules and remove that require?

Comment: @RaajNadar that way I would have to edit that file every time I clone the repository. Theoretically it would work, but I'm not willing to commit that solution.

Comment: Send a pull request!

Comment: @RaajNadar The thing that I'd be removing is important to keep normally. The only reason why I'm trying to remove it is because React Native doesn't support it.